# how do I take (req.param ) through input & button instead of typing in URL bar

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

I am trying to take input from user and sending them to the URL which they typed in.

By concatenating it with url = "http://localhost:3000/"+"/:userInput"

First I tried to take input from user and created a link using DOM method

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("newLis").value;
  document.getElementById("btn").href ='/' + x;
 console.dir(x);
}
</script>
```

And tried to attach it to link href, but it didn't work.

Second, I tried to access the input value through post route
and tried to directly send it in

```
app.get("/:pathName",(req,res)=>{
const pathName = _.capitalize(req.params.pathName);



//console.log(Array.isArray(pathName));
List.findOne({name : pathName}, (error, results)=>{

  if (!error){
    if(!results){
  //prompt("Hello! I am an alert box!");
     const list = new List({
     name : pathName,
     items : def
        })
     list.save();
     List.aggregate();
     res.redirect('/' + pathName);
  }else {
    res.render("list", {listTitle: results.name, newListItems: results.items});
      }
  }
});
});
```

But I don't know how it works.

Answer (score 1):

id of "newLis" and then set the href attribute of an element with an id of "btn" to the value of the user input with "/" appended to the beginning.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

In post request get the value of the URL typed by the user using `req.body.name`. Concatenate the strings to get the full path and then redirect the user to the path

```
app.post("/yourpath",(req,res)=>
{
  const path= "/"+req.body.name;
  res.redirect("path");
}
```

Here name is value of name attribute in input tag.

Comment: well this works but where i need it to work there its not working.

Comment: for example : i am trying this method i guess  i am wrong :   '
<form class="new" action="/" method="post">
  <input id="newLis" type="text" name="newL" placeholder="Enter New List Name" >
  <button id="button" class="btn" type="submit" name="newLiNa" onclick="myFunction()">Create</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

  document.getElementById('button').onclick = ()=>{
    let host = location.host
    let x = document.getElementById("newLis").value;
     location.href = host + '/' + x ;
  }
</script>'

Comment: This code is correct . What error are you getting?